# how to set default image if image src is not valid in nativescript anguar

Tags: angular2-nativescript

how to set default image If image src is failed in nativescript with angualr2

i tried more times,but i can't set default image.
this is my code

any one know answer to solve this problem please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [plugin](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-image) it has the functionality you require you can use

> failureImageUri="your url"